# Rendered font does not exist in my react project

Tags: reactjs, fonts, global, styled-components

I have an issue with my react project. I have had some problems with importing fonts, played around and now the only font that is working is the one that does not even exist in my project, because I intentionally deleted it. I deleted my node modules, I deleted cache I ran server in incognito mode, tried on different browsers. What could be the problem? I use styled-components, and I set my font in my Global.js file. The only thing that helps if I remove font-family from the Global.js file, then it becomes default font.

I tried:

Fallback Mechanism

Checked for Other Stylesheets
React Hot Reload
Font Stacks
Checked Network Requests: no font is loaded
Checked File System
Restarted Browser
Cleared cache, ran server in incognito